# How to format PHP querystring like time:bgcolor:fgcolor?

Tags: php

I have seen a script which doesn't have query string without key, here is the working link to the script.
http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/php/asst/time.php?eng:brown:white

Where eng is the time format identifier, other possible options are comp and compact
brown is foreground color
and white is background color of the page

I have never made query strings without key pairs, my question is How can I make my query string like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and parse as you need. For example

```
$args = explode(':', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$format = $args[0];
$fgcolor = $args[1];
$bgcolor = $args[2];
```